# Bash script - How do I redirect output from a bash script to a file?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell, script

So I have a basic file which shows memory usage, switches, threads etc and I want those results to be printed to a log file, a text file. At the moment I launch my command by typing "./file.sh 1 1" whereas first argument determine how many loops it will run the command, and second argument determine how long it will sleep. Its basically a while looping running all those commands.

I want to export the results to a logfile to keep track, at the end my goal is to have this running over a 24 hour period and log all the results.

I basically want all of this to fly into a log file, if I do add > log.txt or >> log.txt it will print it into the logfile just as I want. But it doesnt show up in the terminal.

```
    echo "Threads:"
        grep -s '^Threads' /proc/[0-9]*/status | awk '{ sum += $2; } END { print sum; }' > log.txt
        echo""
        echo "Free memory:"
        grep MemFree /proc/meminfo > log.txt
        echo ""
        echo "Firefox usage"
        pidstat -C firefox -w -u > log.txt
        echo ""
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you clarify on your expected results/output?

Comment: @kenorb is absolutely right.  You should give us more than this.. but I will throw you a [bone](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).  One more thing.. in another terminal while you are logging.. you can `tail` the log file to see what is getting pumped into it.

Comment: Guys, guys, guys... Just let him type `./file.sh 1 1 | tail -F file_sh_output.txt` and let him see what he really wants to do.

Comment: You are correct. I edited my first thread to make it more clear. And no Dobre, I want it to be written into the bash script, and it would be prefered if I could stick to one line, such as > log.txt at the end of the while loop, instead of having to type it at the end of every line.

Comment: Yes, @SYN was right. I thought of `tee` myself, but somehow I got stuck to @Señor CMasMas' comment and used the `tail` version. Why do you want it written inside the `bash` Shell-Script? And where is the `while` loop? I would still use the `./file.sh 1 1 | tee -a file_sh_output.txt` One-Liner. You can use an alias for it in order to type less.

Comment: I pretty much got it figured out now with the tee command as provided by SYN below. However if I were to just export it and having the terminal blank, what should I change? Tee does the job I asked for, but for future references it would always be nice to have the terminal be blank or just add another echo such as "Exported to blabla.txt", and not clutter the screen with all the output.

Comment: You have to use Mentions such as @DOBRESCU_Mihai , otherwise this _Super User_ Spider is not stinging me enough so that I know that you have written to me. As far as I understand, you did not need either the _tail_ Command, or the _tee_ Command. You just wanted a Plain Redirection to a File using the `>` Operator or the `>>` Operator.

Comment: If you _do_ use the `tee` Command, then you _will_ have your Terminal blank, except for those `echo` Commands. I do not know why they are not redirected as well. Try to search the Internet for this remaining Issue. Or, instead of trying to fix the Issue related to the non-redirected `echo` Commands, you could simply use a `./file.sh 1 1 > file_sh_output.txt` One-Liner. It _will_ also redirect them. You can create an alias for it so that you type less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to both log to file and output to stdout, you may want to try `tee`:

```
    echo "Threads:"
    grep -s '^Threads' /proc/[0-9]*/status | awk '{ sum += $2; } END { print sum; }' | tee -a log.txt
    echo""
    echo "Free memory:"
    grep MemFree /proc/meminfo | tee -a log.txt
    echo ""
    echo "Firefox usage"
    pidstat -C firefox -w -u | tee -a log.txt
    echo ""
```

If you want everything to be sent to your log file, we could instead use:

```
(
    echo "Threads:"
    grep -s '^Threads' /proc/[0-9]*/status | awk '{ sum += $2; } END { print sum; }'
    echo""
    echo "Free memory:"
    grep MemFree /proc/meminfo
    echo ""
    echo "Firefox usage"
    pidstat -C firefox -w -u
    echo ""
) | tee -a log.txt
```

Comment: Perfect. If I were to export all of this to the file, but not have it show up on the terminal, what would be appropriate then? > did work but it doesn't work for echos.

Comment: --edited answer redirecting everything to log file